# rChart graph not getting saved properly

Tags: r, rcharts

This is my code:

```
library(datasets)
library(rCharts)
haireye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
n1 = nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', type = 'multiBarChart', data = subset(haireye, Sex == 'Male'))
n1$save('fig/n1.html', cdn = TRUE)
cat('<iframe.src = "fight/n1.html" width = 100%, height = 600></iframe>')
```

If I just run

```
n1
```

it opens up the graph. However, when I try to open the saved file, it only displays a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran your code and was able to open `n1.html` without any problems, so at least it doesn't seem to be a coding problem.

Comment: Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm on a Mac. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Not sure. Hopefully someone will have some suggestions. I ran your code on a mac and opened the file in Firefox.

Comment: Change n1$save('fig/n1.html', cdn = TRUE) to n1$save('fig/n1.html', standalone = TRUE), I'm pretty sure there was a post on that.